# Generate Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 yaml spec file from a Spring Boot 3.0 project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, swagger, openapi

I need to generate a Swagger/OpenApi (preferably 2.0) `.yaml` spec file for an existing Spring Boot 3.0 restful api project. I don't want to have a swagger-ui page because this project isn't meant to be public. I just want to generate the `.yaml` file to use elsewhere.

I looked around at plugins and tools to do this but things like springfox are no longer maintained for Spring Boot 3.0.

What is the way in 2023 to quickly generate a Swagger/OpenAPI `.yaml` spec file?

I'm using IntelliJ IDE.

Comment: Have you tried ? https://editor.swagger.io/ or Swag by Redocly plug-in for VSCode ? or Open-Api  swagger editor for IntelliJ IDEA ?

Comment: @Harsh Those options you listed look like they are for editing an existing openapi spec file. I need a way to generate one for my Spring Boot project at build time (or however else it can scan my application).

Comment: There are several ways to do so , you may create your own structure which adheres to spring-open api resources structure, alternatively , check if this helps too https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-openapi-documentation , for the folder structure and maven/gradle plugin refer this https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-openapi/

Comment: [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/) is really your only option, however it supports OpenAPI 3+ not 2. It also provides a configuration to disable Swagger UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use [springdoc](https://springdoc.org/#getting-started) with the [gradle plugin](https://springdoc.org/#gradle-plugin) or [maven plugin](https://springdoc.org/#maven-plugin).

This will allow you to run `gradle clean generateOpenApiDocs` to generate the docs for gradle. There are various configurations you can set as shown on the [gradle github](https://gradle%20clean%20generateOpenApiDocs) project.

You can disable the Swagger UI or springdocs as Cisco said [like this](https://springdoc.org/#disabling-the-springdoc-openapi-endpoints):

```
# Disabling the /v3/api-docs endpoint
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false

# Disabling the swagger-ui
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=false
```

This produces an openapi 3 spec but you can [convert it to openapi 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637299/convert-openapi-3-0-to-swagger-2-0).